# How can I store post rankings that change with time?

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn how to code a website algorithm like Reddit.com where there are thousands of posts that need to be ranked. Their ranking algorithm works like this (you don't have to read it, its more of a general question that I have): http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588

Right now I have posts stored in a database, I record their dates and they each have an upvotes and downvotes field so I'm storing their records. I want to figure out how do you store their rankings? When specific posts have ranking values, but they change with time, how could you store their rankings?

If they aren't stored, do you rank every post every time a user loads the page?

When would you store the posts? Do you run a cron job to automatically give every post a new value every x minutes? Do you store their value? Which is temporary. Maybe, until that post reaches its minimum score and is forgotten?

Comment: It is possible to store the rank in the post row, and update it whenever a user upvotes/downvotes/unvotes. Then, you could just get some, ordered by the ranking.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question was asked about 6 months ago.  You should look for that thread.

Answer (score 1):

I did actually read the explanation of the ranking system and if I'm correct they do not care about the *current* time, but the *time of submission of the post*. This means the score will change on two points; 1) when the post is submitted, 2) when someone up- or downvotes the post

So you have to (re-)calculate the score when you post something, and when someone up- or downvotes. To recalculate the score isn't that heavy for the server (not at all actually), so just recalculate on vote-changes!

Answer (score 0):

You would most probably use some sort of cache. In addition to `post_time`, `up_votes`, and `down_votes`, you'd have a `current_rank`, and `last_ranked`. If `last_ranked` would be more than say, 20 minutes, you'd rank it again, and if not, display the cached rank.

A different approach would be to rank and save the rank (i.e. `current_rank`) every time the post is upvoted or downvoted, as well as periodically (every X minutes), then you can just ask the database for the rank, at it would be (pretty) up to date.